# android emulator shows nothing while running by netbeans

Tags: java, android, netbeans, android-virtual-device, android-sdk-2.3

I'm trying to run my first **android hello world program**, i already had setup **Android SDK** and install the required packages, then make a virtual devices using **AVD Manager**, then configuring *android* and *sdk* in **netbeans7.4**. I made a new regular *android project* in netbeans with a regular configurations :

[image]

then tried to run it on a device i created using **AVD** but only got that result :

[image]

**and this is the debug result**

```
ant -f C:\\Users\\HP\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\haha debug
Android SDK Tools Revision 22.3.0
Installed at D:\Solace Android\Solace Data\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130729\sdk
Project Name: haha
Project Type: Application
Using latest Build Tools: 19.0.0
Resolving Build Target for haha...
Project Target:   Android 4.4
API level:        19
WARNING: No minSdkVersion value set. Application will install on all Android versions.
----------
Creating output directories if needed...
Created dir: C:\Users\HP\Documents\NetBeansProjects\haha\bin
Created dir: C:\Users\HP\Documents\NetBeansProjects\haha\bin\res
Created dir: C:\Users\HP\Documents\NetBeansProjects\haha\bin\rsObj
Created dir: C:\Users\HP\Documents\NetBeansProjects\haha\bin\rsLibs
Created dir: C:\Users\HP\Documents\NetBeansProjects\haha\gen
Created dir: C:\Users\HP\Documents\NetBeansProjects\haha\bin\classes
Created dir: C:\Users\HP\Documents\NetBeansProjects\haha\bin\dexedLibs
----------
Resolving Dependencies for haha...
Library dependencies:
No Libraries
------------------
----------
Building Libraries with 'debug'...
No sub-builds to iterate on
Merging AndroidManifest files into one.
Manifest merger disabled. Using project manifest only.
Handling aidl files...
No AIDL files to compile.
----------
Handling RenderScript files...
----------
Handling Resources...
Generating resource IDs...
----------
Handling BuildConfig class...
Generating BuildConfig class.
Compiling 3 source files to C:\Users\HP\Documents\NetBeansProjects\haha\bin\classes
input: C:\Users\HP\Documents\NetBeansProjects\haha\bin\classes
Converting compiled files and external libraries into C:\Users\HP\Documents\NetBeansProjects\haha\bin\classes.dex...
Crunching PNG Files in source dir: C:\Users\HP\Documents\NetBeansProjects\haha\res
To destination dir: C:\Users\HP\Documents\NetBeansProjects\haha\bin\res
Processing image to cache: C:\Users\HP\Documents\NetBeansProjects\haha\res\drawable-hdpi\ic_launcher.png => C:\Users\HP\Documents\NetBeansProjects\haha\bin\res\drawable-hdpi\ic_launcher.png
  (processed image to cache entry C:\Users\HP\Documents\NetBeansProjects\haha\bin\res\drawable-hdpi\ic_launcher.png: 87% size of source)
Processing image to cache: C:\Users\HP\Documents\NetBeansProjects\haha\res\drawable-ldpi\ic_launcher.png => C:\Users\HP\Documents\NetBeansProjects\haha\bin\res\drawable-ldpi\ic_launcher.png
  (processed image to cache entry C:\Users\HP\Documents\NetBeansProjects\haha\bin\res\drawable-ldpi\ic_launcher.png: 0% size of source)
Processing image to cache: C:\Users\HP\Documents\NetBeansProjects\haha\res\drawable-mdpi\ic_launcher.png => C:\Users\HP\Documents\NetBeansProjects\haha\bin\res\drawable-mdpi\ic_launcher.png
  (processed image to cache entry C:\Users\HP\Documents\NetBeansProjects\haha\bin\res\drawable-mdpi\ic_launcher.png: 78% size of source)
Processing image to cache: C:\Users\HP\Documents\NetBeansProjects\haha\res\drawable-xhdpi\ic_launcher.png => C:\Users\HP\Documents\NetBeansProjects\haha\bin\res\drawable-xhdpi\ic_launcher.png
  (processed image to cache entry C:\Users\HP\Documents\NetBeansProjects\haha\bin\res\drawable-xhdpi\ic_launcher.png: 85% size of source)
Crunched 4 PNG files to update cache
Creating full resource package...
Current build type is different than previous build: forced apkbuilder run.
Creating haha-debug-unaligned.apk and signing it with a debug key...
Running zip align on final apk...
Debug Package: C:\Users\HP\Documents\NetBeansProjects\haha\bin\haha-debug.apk
Creating new property file: C:\Users\HP\Documents\NetBeansProjects\haha\bin\build.prop
Updating property file: C:\Users\HP\Documents\NetBeansProjects\haha\bin\build.prop
Updating property file: C:\Users\HP\Documents\NetBeansProjects\haha\bin\build.prop
Updating property file: C:\Users\HP\Documents\NetBeansProjects\haha\bin\build.prop
debug:
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 12 seconds)
```

Comment: What are your PC specs? The AVD is really slow and heavy, so it takes a lot of time to start android (With an i7 3610qm and 8GB ram running linux it takes 3 minutes to start), can you try using [Bluestacks](http://www.bluestacks.com/)?

Comment: i'm working on that with a low specifications laptop, 2M memory and core2due processor

Comment: Then this can be the cause. If you want you can try using BlueStacks, which is really a lot faster than the AVD

Comment: well, i'll try it thanks anywhere

Comment: @BackSlash thanks a lot, it works perfectly with BlueStacks

Comment: Glad that it worked, I'm posting an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your computer specs. The AVD is really slow and heavy, so it takes a lot of time to start Android (with an i7 3610qm and 8GB ram running linux it takes 3 minutes to start, and once started it is very laggy).

Try running Android with [BlueStacks](http://www.bluestacks.com/), it's an android Virtual Device like AVD but IMO it works better, it's a lot faster.